# Is it possible to use a proxy with a 3G connection on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, cellular-data, proxy

I'm currently using a proxy over Wi-Fi connections on my iPhone 4S, but there doesn't seem to be an option to apply it to 3G connections. I tried configuring a configuration profile with iPhone Configuration Utility, but I couldn't seem to find the option. I even tried to add a few keys to the exported "mobileconfig" file, but that didn't seem to work either. How do I apply a proxy server to a 3G connection?

My device is jailbroken, so if there is an easier way of doing this inside the filesystem, that is an option.

Comment: YES it is possible, see answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81102/proxy-settings-for-iphone-3g-connection

Comment: Sadly, I do not have access to a Mac, so Apple Configurator is not something I can use. I did install iPhone Configuration Utility, but it seems to be lacking a lot of the features available in that program.