# How to configure a proxy for the mobile data connection?

Tags: ios, network, proxy

Reasons why I want to configure the proxy is to surf anonymous, for security reasons, to gain access in blocked websites in some locations.

I've seen that it is possible to configure a proxy with the WLAN settings in the iPhone. I may not have access to WLAN all the time so, I'm wondering whether it is also possible to configure a proxy for the mobile data connection.

I found an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81102/proxy-settings-for-iphone-3g-connection/85096#85096) which recommended Apple configurator and wiping the device.

I prefer to use [@Stock B's method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/247194/313842) which states:

> Generate a `mobileconfig` using a tool such as http://iphone.flexserve.net. Load the mobileconfig by opening it in the iOS mail client. Remove it from Device Configuration when you're finished testing.
>   This method neither requires a Mac OS X computer, nor a jailbroken iPhone.

I need someone on here who knows or has used  this method or knows how to configure a proxy for the mobile data connection on iPhone 6 iOS 12.4.

Kindly walk me through it so I don’t make any mistake along the way and ruin my Phone.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me. Instead of asking us how to do something you **think** might be the solution to your issue, try asking us about how to solve the problem you **actually** have.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) The point that Tetsujin is trying to make is that the way your question comes across is that you're asking how to do *this* because you're actually trying to solve another issue or achieve something else. If that's the case, you'd be better off [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/366932/edit) your question to ask about that other issue or whatever else you're trying to achieve. Of course, if that's not the case, perhaps you could still edit your question just to provide more details (e.g. what version of iOS, what you've already tried, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for the edits. What's still not really clear is what kind of answers you expect. You've listed two methods to accomplish this in your post. Did you try them already (and if yes, why don't they fit your need)? If you didn't try them yet, why not just go ahead and do so?

Comment: Nohillside thanks for your comment. The answer I expect is a step by step guidance from someone who has done it and succeed using the 2nd method by StockB. I will like to try it however I will like to try it with a step by step guidance from someone on this forum who can walk me through it step by step till it’s achieved. I feel it’s better to have someone to walk me through it step by step from start to finish  than I trying it alone having problem coming back here to talk about the problem going back to fix it. Please can you kindly ask StockB if he can contact me?

Comment: I made attempts to chat to monomeeth however I couldn’t find how to chat to him I am using my iphone6 I don’t have a laptop yet. Please can someone on here kindly tell me how to chat to someone directly using the persons handle? On monomeeths profile he wrote he can be contacted via chat.

Comment: Why don’t you just try yourself and ask specific questions (with a link back to @stockb‘s Original answer) if you get stuck? The first part (up to opening it in mail) won‘t break anything, the rest is kind of guided anyway.